# Let $a=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ find $a^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

I have worked out $a^2=\langle 2\rangle$ then $a^3=\langle 4,2+2\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ and $a^4=\langle 4\rangle$

Is it correct to say that $a^n=\langle 2^{n-1}\rangle$ for even numbers but I'm not sure about odd numbers.

I'm looking for $a^n$ in the simplest form.

Comment: Can you specify your notation? Do you want to use $\le$ (`\le`)?

Comment: @Karlo I think that $\langle x, y \rangle$ means the ideal generated by numbers $x$ and $y$ and $\langle z \rangle$ means the ideal generated by number $z$. Similarly $a^n$ consists of all products of $n$ elements of the ideal $a$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If $a=\langle r,s\rangle$, then
$$
a^2=\langle r^2,rs,s^2\rangle
$$
so in your case $a^2=\langle 4,2+2\sqrt{-5},-4+2\sqrt{-5}\rangle$. Then $2\sqrt{-5}\in a^2$ and also $2\in a^2$. This (up to some small details) proves that indeed $a^2=\langle 2\rangle$.

Now $a^3=\langle 4,2+2\sqrt{-5}\rangle$(you shouldn't just cube the generators of $a$) and $a^4=\langle 4\rangle$. Can you then use induction after having made a suitable conjecture?

Comment: I don't understand how $a^3=\langle 4\rangle$. For this to be the case then $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ has to be a multiple of 4. So am I right in saying that $a^n=\langle 2^{n-1}\rangle$ In which case you prove by induction in an analogous way to the proof that $a^3=\langle 4\rangle$ but I don't see how it can.

Comment: @BillHayes Sorry, a part was missing

Comment: So $a^n=\langle2^{\frac{n}{2}\rangle$ for even numbers and $a^n=\langle 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}, 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}+ 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}\sqrt{-5}$

Comment: @BillHayes That’s right for the even powers

Comment: $a^n=\langle 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}, 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}+ 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}\sqrt{-5} \rangle$ for the odd powers

Comment: @BillHayes That should be right; the expression is not unique, of course.